# Anchor tag not working in safari mobile

Tags: angularjs, html, anchor

I have anchor tags which are working perfectly fine in safari desktop view, when I switch to mobile view for same the actor tags are not working.

In image below the tags which i commented as anchor1(top) works in both desktop and mobile view however the second anchor2(almost bottom) works only in desktop view not in mobile view. even the css for anhor2 is not working in mobile view.

[image]I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is not working basically? What behaviours you want which is not working?

Comment: So can you just not click the link? Or is it not appearing?

Comment: @mylescc: Link is appearing, I am not able to click it.